# How to change Homepage images

Tags: product-images

How do I change the images in the homepage in CMS? Thank you.

http://siteground121.com/~mataano2/index.php/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about your specific theme.

Comment: Ok i have found thare have use a widget please check there. how to work on theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kab8609 is right this is theme specific, and without seeing any code its hard to say.
However from the source code it looks like it's in a widget. You could try in the following places in the magento backend:

- CMS > Pages > find homepage page
- CMS > Static Blocks > Banner

Good Luck!